# Font didn't change

Tags: html, css, sass

Button font dosent change idk why. Can somebody help me?
I try to put `font-family` in different places but it still don't work
I'm wokrking with scss compiler

```css
body {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper .content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper .content .background-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #080808;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-file {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-file input[type=file] {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(Opacity=0);
  /* Safari  */
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-file .input-style {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  transition: 500ms;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-file .input-style:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-file .sumbit {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-text {
  padding-top: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-text .upload-text-bt {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 254px;
  height: 64px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  transition: 500ms;
}
.wrapper .content .upload-section .upload-text .upload-text-bt:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Awesome Uploader</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/kwr3tvr.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="img/image.png" alt="Background" class="background-image">
            <div class="upload-section">
                <h1>Awesome Uploader</h1>
                <div class="upload-file">
                    <form action="/upload" method="post">
                        <label class="input-style">
                            Choose file<input type="file" name="targetfile" id="targetfile">
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload file" class="sumbit">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="upload-text">
                    <button class="upload-text-bt">Upload text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean proxima-nova? Read about [font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face-in-css/)....

Answer (score 0):

The font you are using is a custom font, you need to import it in your css file or html.

HTML

```
<link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/proxima-nova-2" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS

```
    <style>
    @import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/proxima-nova-2');
    body{
                                                                        
   font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
                                                
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: It is imported `typekit.css` cause im using adobe fonts. Basicly font works everywhere  but not in the button

Comment: Try using this to change the font, it seems to work fine here.
button {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova' !important;
}